# Delay while loading locally stored file on webView

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webview

I am loading locally stored html(files with javascript) file on my `webView`. These files are loaded in my `ViewController.swift`. However, there is a delay of ~2-3 seconds when the app is launched for the first time. I have searched over the web regarding an approach to fix this issue, with the approaches I observed(First loading of the `webView` delays the loading of resources), I have decided to use `NSNotificationCenter` in my `ViewController` and call them from 'AppDelegate' so that the `webView` is loaded first time.

Upon implementation of these changes in my code,  there is delay in the `LaunchScreen` of the application, which is as expected as I am loading a file here, however, the loading time of `ViewController` is still the same.

I am calling the Notifications
`AppDelegate.swift`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("loadDefaultWebViewID",object:nil)


        return true
    }
```

`ViewController.swift`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadDefaultWebView:", name: "loadDefaultWebViewID", object: nil)
    if let htmlURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html") {
        let requestObject = NSURLRequest(URL: htmlURL)
        webViewHTML5Player.loadRequest(requestObject)

    }
```

I wish to reduce the delay that on the `ViewController`.If this is not the correct way, Is there any other better optimized approached to achieve this task ?

**Edit 1**

I have tried using `WKWebView`(with `preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true`) and `UIWebView` for this purpose, loading time is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common problem occuring in  `UIWebView`. My point is to make the web view initially hidden (showing some sort of "Loading..." indicator instead), then make it un-hidden in the `webViewDidFinishLoad: method`. and also you can refer this link [UIWebView lower loading time with a more efficient way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15287381/uiwebview-lower-loading-time-with-a-more-efficient-way) and [Preloading webView doesn't work - trying to reduce loading time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18465408/preloading-webview-doesnt-work-trying-to-reduce-loading-time)